# pymssql error 20009 while connecting to db

Tags: python, database-connection, pymssql

This is driving me crazy and I can't figure out. I installed pymssql on my Mac and was using it without any problem. And then one day it stopped working. I have no idea why. I can run the same code on another box and it works fine, but not my machine, anymore.

When I run this:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(host='aws', user='myUserName', password='myPassWord', database='myDB')
```

I get this error:

```
pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, 'Net-Lib error during Operation now in progress')
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post what do you get on `mysql -h aws -u userName -p` as well.

Comment: I'm connecting to a tsql database not mysql. When I ran your suggestion I got: -bash: mysql: command not found